# How to replace multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

mysql table example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>aa</td><td>1111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bb</td><td>1111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cc</td><td>2222</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>dd</td><td>3333</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ee</td><td>1111</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
```

I am new to here and wondering if any can help me replacing value of 1111s to 4444s with php.
    
I have tried the follow and didn't seem to work:
    
$sql="UPDATE tablename SET `id` = REPLACE(`id`,'1111','4444')";

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VYd26.png) toolbar button. I've done it for you this time. Additionally, try to avoid "does not work" as sole description: it's like saying nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should replace the `value`,not the `ID`

```
$sql="UPDATE tablename SET `value` = REPLACE(`value`,'1111','4444')";
```

or simply

```
$sql="UPDATE tablename SET `value` = '4444' WHERE value = '1111'";
```

Comment: I'd vote for the second one. If you use the first one, and you have some value like '32111123', you will end up with '32444423'. String replaces should be avoided if you can :-)

Comment: I know it's a dummy value as an example and not the actual value you want to replace, but you get the point ;-).

Comment: @Flater I agree, but i was wondering that there are other records existed that the op wants to replace value which contain on a speified contain `:D`

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tablename SET value = "4444" WHERE value = "1111"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tablename
SET    value='4444'
WHERE  value='1111'
```